# question update

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, уведомления

Предположительно не переведён текст в уведомлении о переоткрытии вопроса:

> question update

> Hooray, this question was reopened! Anyone can answer it now.

[image: скриншот]

PS: Для минусаторов замечу, что другие фразы с англоязычных сайтов переведены, если открывать панель уведомлений на ruSO.

Answer (score 2):

Предложил:

https://ru.traducir.win/string/13590

> Ура, этот вопрос был переоткрыт! Теперь любой может ответить на него.

https://ru.traducir.win/string/13591

> обновление вопроса

Comment: Утвердил предложения.

Comment: "question update" выкатилось. А вот второе пока нет почему-то. Подождём до следующей ревизии движка. Либо появится, либо там хардкод. Вполне вероятно, что сам текст (его язык) зависит от того, на каком сайте действие. Что-то такое уже было.

Comment: «был переоткрыт» как-то не звучит, по-моему что-то вроде «этот вопрос снова открыт» было бы получше